# How was task gradle implemented to be used in the way that's currently used?

Tags: groovy, gradle, implementation

I'm learning gradle and for that reason I began to learn groovy.
I don't understand how gradle or groovy allows me to do this:

```
task nameOfTask(dependsOn: otherTask) {
    //some stuff
}
```

If task is a class, nameOfTask would need to use the operator new to be instantiated. If task is a method, nameOfTask, I think, would need to be a String.

Please can you post an example code that allows me to reproduce the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting (and contextualizing) the answer to the same question on the [gradle discussion forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-translate-task-keyword-in-dsl-into-groovy-call/7243)

> the snippet above is resolved to a method call
>
> Project#task("nameOfTask", dependsOn: otherTask)
>
> to get this working with the snippet above, AST transformation is used. See http://www.groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_compile_time_metaprogramming for more details